# Laravel schedule runs but the code doesn't

Tags: php, laravel, cron, centos7, almalinux

I have set Laravel schedule:run by cronjob and the problem is the cronjob runs the command successfully and outputs the result, but the code doesn't run and nothing shown in processes on the server.
But when I manually run schedule:run it works fine and the codes run.

Cronjob is working fine and there is no problem with Php version.

I use Laravel 5.8 with php 7.1 and Almalinux as a server with directadmin.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Do you have the actual cronjob running? `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`? Sounds like that is not working as expected.

Comment: Post your cronjob command. We aren't psychic.

Comment: I check and yes cronjob is running well and outputs like this: `Running scheduled command: ('/usr/local/php71/bin/php71' 'artisan' crawl:feeds 100 50 > '/dev/null' 2>&1 ; '/usr/local/php71/bin/php71' 'artisan' schedule:finish "framework/schedule-5f774a4b94b406d49391cf28a7fb25f3034d61a2") > '/dev/null' 2>&1 &` but the command does not run! I set the command to put the time in a file named time.txt when it runs but nothing is getting saved in that file! When I run schedule manually from cmd the file gets updated well and shows the last time command ran.

Comment: My cronjob cmd is `cd /home/user/domains/domain.com && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` it works fine because it sends outputs every minute as I mentioned above.

Comment: Another thing is the schedule runs by cronjob just one time and after it, it outputs like this: `No scheduled commands are ready to run.`